# Javascript parsing the html text error at json at position x

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, escaping

Here is my js fiddle and the text i been trying to escape so far the php code i tried to escape these characters

```
 $datas[] = ['attributes' => [$colorId => ['id' => $child->getColor(),
                                    'name' => $product->getName(),
                                    'productId' => $product->getId(),
                                    'price' => number_format($product->getSpecialPrice(),2),
                                    'rrp' => number_format($product->getMsrp(), 2),
                                    'was' => number_format($product->getPrice(), 2),
                                    'image' =>  Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $child->getImage(),
                                    'size' => $child->getSize(),
                                    'description' =>Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(htmlspecialchars(json_encode($product->getDescription()), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false)),

                                    // Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($product->getDescription()),
                                    'promo' => Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($product->getProductpromobox()),
                                    'sku' => $product->getSku(),
                                    'netsuite' => $product->getInternalId()
                                    ],

                                    $sizeId => ['id' => $child->getSize(),
                                    'name' => $product->getName(),
                                    'productId' => $product->getId(),
                                    'price' => number_format($product->getSpecialPrice(),2),
                                    'rrp' => number_format($product->getMsrp(), 2),
                                    'was' => number_format($product->getPrice(), 2),
                                    'image' =>  Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $child->getImage(),
                                    'color' => $child->getColor(),
                                    'description' => Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(json_encode(utf8_encode($product->getDescription()), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false)),

                                    // Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($product->getDescription()),
                                    'promo' => Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($product->getProductpromobox()),
                                    'sku' => $product->getSku(),
                                     'netsuite' => $product->getInternalId()]

                                    ]];
```

In my javascript file i did was

```
var productConfig = '<?php echo json_encode($datas);?>';
```

so this is the php code so error is only at description key while parsing
https://jsfiddle.net/tsjfkwto/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include the `'`s:

```
var productConfig = <?php echo json_encode($datas);?>;
// No ' here -------^--------------------------------^
```

`json_encode` outputs a valid JavaScript value for the right-hand side of an assignment (because JSON is a subset of JavaScript literal syntax). If you're encoding a simple string, it will have appropriate quotes; if you're encoding an object structure, it will have the correct object structure (which shouldn't be in quotes).